# How to get the index of remaining string index after regexp in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have already got the matched string using regular expression in python as following.

```
import re
matches = re.finditer(r'<\S+?>',' Hi <a> This is </a> an example! ')
for match in matches:
    print(
        "matched string: '%s', start index: %s, end index: %s"
        % (match.group(0), match.span(0)[0], match.span(0)[1])
    )
```

result in:

```
matched string: '<a>', start index: 4, end index: 7
matched string: '</a>', start index: 16, end index: 20
```

now I want to get remaining string index, something like:

```
[0,4],[7,16],[20,33]
```

Comment: What is your end goal? If you simply wish to remove the tags and keep the strings, you can just use regex replace

Comment: i have to highlight the text in an online editor that not matching a few regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should give you the expected output:

```
import re
str = ' Hi <a> This is </a> an example! '
matches = re.finditer(r'<\S+?>',str)
start = 0
output = []
for match in matches:
    output.append([start,match.start()])
    start = match.end()
output.append([start,len(str)])

print(output)
```

## Output:

```
[[0, 4], [7, 16], [20, 33]]
```

Comment: Note that `match.span(0)[0]` = `match.start()` and `match.span(0)[1]` = `match.end()`. `<\S+?>` is equal to a more efficient `<[^\s>]+>`